# RestKit - Entity Mapping Property transformation

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I need to map a web service with object properties all in caps against coredata object properties all in lowercase:

```json
# JSON
{
    'ID': 'value',
    'TITLE': 'value',
    'BODY': 'value',
}
# CoreData Entity
{
    'id': 'value',
    'title': 'value',
    'body': 'value',
}
```

I mapped the fields by doing:

```c
RKEntityMapping *entMap = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:entName 
    inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] 
    objectForKey:entName];
[entMap addAttributeMappingsFromArray:[[[RKPropertyInspector sharedInspector]
    propertyInspectionForEntity:entity] allKeys]];
```

I saw this convenient [`setDefaultSourceToDestinationKeyTransformationBlock`](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0-pre2/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html#//api/name/setDefaultSourceToDestinationKeyTransformationBlock%3a) fonction in [`RKObjectMapping`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html) allowing to define custom transformation on object properties. This is not available on [`RKEntityMapping`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKEntityMapping.html).

How can I do property transformations with `RKEntityMapping` without defining fields manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current work-around:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictToArray:(NSArray *)array
    withTranformation:(NSString *(^)(NSString *))theBlock
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in array) {
        dict[theBlock(key)] = key;
    }
    return dict;
}

NSArray *fields = [[[RKPropertyInspector sharedInspector] 
    propertyInspectionForEntity:entity] allKeys];
NSDictionary *mapDict = [self dictToArray:fields
    withTranformation:^NSString *(NSString *str) {
        return [str uppercaseString];
    }];

[entMap addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mapDict];
```